# Group Names and Average the Corresponding Values (Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The data is stored in csv file. I use pd.read_csv to load data from csv into python. I am looking for a way to group the names which have the same first name before the space, and sum then average the corresponding values from Score1 and Score2 using pandas.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Names':['Jason','Jason S','Dan','Dan S'],'Score1':[30,np.nan,20,40],'Score2':[40,60,30,np.nan]})

Names         Score1    Score2
Jason         30        40
Jason S       NaN       60
Dan           20        30
Dan S         40        NaN
```

I want to see the dataframe as the following as the result.

```
Names         Score1     Score2
Jason         15         50
Dan           30         15
```

I have the following codes so far and it just does the grouping, nothing else.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['Names'], as_index=False)['Score1', 'Score2'].sum().mean())
print(df1)
```

I would appreciate any hints. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far? In terms of code

Comment: @Jesse. Just added the codes. It is not the right way to do, I guess.

Comment: Can you try df.groupby('Names').apply(lambda x: x.sum())?

Comment: @Jesse. I tried that and it grouped Jason, not Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `str.split` to get group key

```
df.fillna(0).groupby(df.Names.str.split(' ',expand=True)[0]).mean()
Out[352]: 
       Score1  Score2
0                    
Dan      30.0    15.0
Jason    15.0    50.0
```

Comment: @CullenDuYaw yw ~! :-)